# Django first app: error during the creation of sql tables from my models

Tags: python, django, django-models, pycharm

I'm new in Python and I would  to start some tutorial using Django.

I would use PyCharm as IDE.

So, I tried to create my start Django project.

I use a Mac, Python 2.7.5 version, Django 1.7.5 version.

I follow [this tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/) to create my first Django app.

When I try to crate SQL Tables (in Pycharm I use this command: Alt + R, sql command and the name of my app example) I have this error:

```
bash -cl "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py sql FirstExample /Users/Gianluigi/PycharmProjects/mycompany"
CommandError: App 'FirstExample' has migrations. Only the sqlmigrate and sqlflush commands can be used when an app has migrations.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Django 1.7 comes with built-in migration system, you should use it instead.

Comment: You're not following that tutorial. Nowhere on that page does it say to run `manage.py sql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `sql` command. Assuming you have your database information correctly set up in settings.py, your `python manage.py ...` will be able to do everything for you.

In this case you would do `python manage.py makemigrations mycompany` followed by `python manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we have an app users. Add that app to settings

models.py:

```
class User(Django_User):
    observations = CharField(max_length=2048, null=True, blank=True)
```

you should run the following command first to create the migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

This will create your database tables

That's it!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/

Answer (score 0):

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/django_guide.html

while following this link, in CREATING DATABASE section when it says use the magic Ctrl+Alt+R shortcut twice: 
we actually use it once and in console type **makemigrations**  and then **migrate**